# Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.6

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, react-native

I'm trying to run a React Native project but I'm getting the following error:

[image]

I searched on the web but without success.

This is my **build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
apply plugin: "com.github.ben-manes.versions"

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.6'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        google()
    }
}
```

This is my **gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.6`. 4.6 is a Gradle version. The Android Gradle Plugin versions follow Android Studio versions. So, the latest production Android Gradle Plugin is `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1`.

So, change:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.6'
```

to:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
```